# Install an Oracle DB in a linux VM

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, virtualbox, oracle

I am trying to set up an Oracle database server (at the moment just for testing purposes) in a virtual machine.

The setup I'm using:

- VirtualBox
- Network adapter in NAT mode (redirecting ports 22->22, 80->80, 1521->1521, 8080->8080)

  - I'd rather avoid bridged networking, if possible
  - It would be good if the database could be accessed by the outside world, and not just the host OS
- CentOS 6.4 64-bit
- Oracle XE, version 11.2.0.2.0 "Production", installed and configured using the default ports (1521 and 8080)
- Firewall disabled in both the guest OS and the host OS
- The host OS is behind a proxy

**The problem**

I cannot access the database (over port 1521, using sqlplus or SQL developer) from the host. I can access it from the VM itself though (using sqlplus).

I can also SSH from the host into the VM and I can access the web interface from the host when I navigate to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex
```

Therefore, the NAT setup of VirtualBox seems to work to some extent.

It seems the listener is up when I execute *lsnctrl status*. The listener.ora file looks like this:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

When I try to connect from the host, I get the following error (the same command works when executed within CentOS):

```
PS C:\Users\winuser> sqlplus system/thepassword@127.0.0.1

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Fr Jul 12 16:56:25 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Port 1521 also seems to be active in the VM, and port forwarding is set up appropriately in VirtualBox:

```
[root@localhost admin]# nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-12 17:02 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
631/tcp  open  ipp
1521/tcp open  oracle
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

Thank you for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid bridged networking?

Comment: Because I would like the database to be accessible when clients connect to my machine. With bridged networking, the virtual machine appears as a separate machine on the network. I'd use bridged if there is no other solution though.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot connect to database using only IP address.

Run

```
lsnrctl status
```

on guest machine to find out service name and instance name (ORCL for example). Then edit tnsnames.ora on host machine similar to this:

```
ORCL=
(DESCRIPTION=
 (ADDRESS=
   (PROTOCOL=TCP)
   (HOST=127.0.0.1)
   (PORT=1521)
 )
 (CONNECT_DATA=
   (SERVER=dedicated)
   (SERVICE_NAME=your_service_name_here)
 )
)
```

and try TNSPINGing it:

```
tnsping ORCL
```

It sould say something like "Ok (20 msec.)"
At last run sqlplus:

```
sqlplus user/password@ORCL
```

For more information read Oracle Documentation:
http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=4&frame=#network_management

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with your Oracle network configuration. Either use network manager or hand-edit sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I assume the network manager is a graphical application (the CentOS server does not have a graphical server installed)? I noticed I don't have an sqlnet.ora file, is this a mandatory file?